# Get path geometry from image

Tags: wpf, silverlight, pathgeometry

If i have a logo, let's say done as a jpg or even a png. Any suggestion for how I can use that to define a path geometry?  It would be really good if any suggestions could be provided for how i can do it in blend.
Thanks

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Yes - I just tackled this problem for an LOB application two days ago.

I can't offer advice for Blend (though I've read that it can be done in Expression Designer). However, the best *free* tool I've found for this is called InkScape (http://www.inkscape.org).

It's opensource, and while it's intended primarily for editing SVG vector-based images, it has two key features that are useful to us WPFers:

1. It can vectorize (i.e. "trace") raster images like bitmaps and jpegs, albeit not as well as one would hope, and
2. It can export the vector image as XAML

You'll invariably find that you get better results from loading vector formats (like SVG, EMF, WMF, etc) and saving to XAML, than if you try to convert a bitmap/jpeg... simply because the process of vectorizing a raster image is error prone at best. So if you want to bring a company logo into XAML, try to get hold of the source files used to create the logo (perhaps done in Illustrator?) and import that into InkScape.

If this post is helpful, please be kind and give it a one-up.

Comment: If you have some trouble with inkscape (like me) there is a good tutorial : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1cZk08x_rAI

Answer (score 3):

[Jasema](http://marlongrech.wordpress.com/jasema/) is a terrific tool right for the job.

Also, don't be shy to use Blend - it is somewhat more difficult to use (drawing shapes using pen) but it gets easier pretty fast. Switch on gridlines and optionally snap to them for good results.

What both Jasema and Blend are lacking, is the ability to easily create shapes with a central symmetry (like stars), so I took parts from Jasema and created my own tool (named Radius) that works a bit like a combination of a ruler and compass.

Answer (score 3):

I have a good idea but you're png, bmp, jpg or other non vector file is must be very simple because we need best scan results and only use inkscape.

1. Step: Drag and drop your file workspace on **Inkscape**, **[download free](https://inkscape.org)**.

Tip: If your image is color white, Top menu item **File**->**Document Properties**-> heck **Checkerboard Background** and if you want uncheck **Page border show**.

2. Step: Top menu item **Path**-> **Trace Bitmap**-> **Mode** check what you want property, *i usually* *use* **color** property and if your file is png check Remove Background then click **OK**, then wait again Ok button **is Enable** and close window.
3. Step: Now you have a two layer, top layer vektor file and bottom layer your file. **Select vector file** and top menu item **Edit**-> **XML Editor**-> select *svg path* and look side column, **d name** propery in your data path **value**.

But this method may not always work or may not give the desired results and draw your own shapes with the scape so you can get the path data from the XML editor.

Example, my first tests this like:[image]

and after working on it some more:[image]

Answer (score 2):

I've solved my problem (export an image as XAML) using Microsoft Expression Design 4 (Free Version). I've downloaded from the link 
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=36180

As input, I had Adobe Ilustrator files.

Answer (score 1):

Adobe Illustrator / CorelDraw is perhaps the best tool out there for these operations that I have used.
Personally, I prefer illustrator for on-screen media. These tracings can be exported into several formats such as EPS, SVG, AI, or even XAML (with this [plugin](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mswanson/archive/2009/01/31/updated-adobe-illustrator-to-xaml-plug-in.aspx))

Best of Luck !!!!

Answer (score 0):

I have recently been struggling with this myself. I had a set of icons done in data and needed to update them to look nicer.

I tried everything, manually typing them out. drawing in svg, converting svg to xaml.

in the end i found a list of open source icons from google material icons.

I then used this to convert from the svg files to data
https://github.com/BerndK/SvgToXaml

It works well but not for the icons i drew myself.

I decided to place all the icons data i convert into an app i built myself that will give you the data and a preview of the icon. feel free to use and contribute. I will keep updating as much as i can.
https://github.com/sgreaves1/XamlIcons

Answer (score 0):

Convert your image from png to svg in online converter, then drop file into this site http://inloop.github.io/svg2android/ and you will see pathData of your image like below shown in my image.
[image]