# Source for basic Shapes in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, pathgeometry

Does anybody know if there is some online source where one can download basic shapes such as the minimize/ maximize glyph, a star geometry or the Visual Studio pin glyph as WPF GEometry Path?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/983092/get-path-geometry-from-image

Comment: Snoop can help you (but you will have to have an application with all the glyphs;) or Resharper, but these path are usually declared in XAML as resources...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Expression Blend you can find Shapes for WPF.
http://www.microsoft.com/expression/products/blend_overview.aspx

Assets->Shapes

Answer (score 0):

If you have a favorite WPF app, you could also use [Snoop](https://github.com/snoopwpf/snoopwpf) to look at the shapes in that app and use them as a starting point.

Please do not just rip other people's hard work off!