# How to do picture shaped button in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

I want a picture with transparent background to be a button.

[image: Here's the picture]

The shape of the picture is custom (not an ellipse or something like that). So, I need it to be lighted and be possible to press (in the shape of 1 itself!).

I've only started working on WPf and don't know how to do this. And I couldn't really figure out how to do it in my case (although there are alike questions on the platform).

Would be very thankful if you give me a detailed answer!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [WPF Button with Image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2697383/wpf-button-with-image)

Comment: No, this way I'll have a rectangular area for the button and I want it to be the sape of 1.

Comment: Are you sure this should really be a bitmap? How about a Path, i.e. vector graphics?

Comment: @Clemens I'm not sure how to make it work in vector graphics (I  have 7 of those numbers and all of them should be buttons). Maybe you could share any link so that I could understand vectors in WPF?

Comment: Do you already have these numbers as image files, i.e. PNGs?

Comment: Yes, they are all PNGs.

Comment: And you definitely want it to be hit-test visible only in the non-transparent parts, i.e. when the suer clicks on the transparent image background, the Button's Click event should not be fired?

Comment: In the best case - yes. 
If it's not really possible, I will try to change the images and make them rectangular.

Comment: That would by far be the easiest approach, unless you want to recreate the numbers as vector graphics. Then an Image element in the ControlTemplate of a Button would work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you need to handle a limited number of pictures and if all of them are relatively simple like that "1" the task seems doable. The most challenging part is to construct the geometry element that cuts the button in its specific shape. If you only have the images in raster formats (*.png, *.jpg, *.bmp - a rectangular map of colored pixels), you will first have to them to vector images (presented with a set of mathematical functions instead of pixel data). It is not a trivial task, but if an image has a simple outline, you should be able to get good results. There are different pieces of software that handle this problem. [Here](https://logosbynick.com/inkscape-convert-png-to-svg/) is some blog post on this topic, but if does not meet your needs, you can also search for "How to trace a raster image", "Convert a raster image to a vector one" etc. If you are successful at this step, you will get some SVG images. Alas WPF does not support SVG images, as it has its own "language" for translating geometry data. So the svgs should be translated to WPF [Geometries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.geometry?view=netframework-4.8). I found some blogs while looking for "SVG to XAML", "SVG to WPF path" etc. [Here](https://liftcodeplay.com/2015/09/14/converting-vectorsvg-images-into-xaml/) is one with several approaches to the task.
When you have the WPF Geometries, you will be able to cut the button like this:

```
    <Button>
        <Button.Template>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <Image Source=". . .">
                    <Image.Clip>
                        <Geometry . . . />
                    </Image.Clip>
                </Image>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Button.Template>
    </Button>
```

Of course, you can make it much more maintainable if you can create a custom control type that has the image data and geometry data exposed as properties, and then bind them in the template.

On the bottom line, this is not an easy task, which can become even more cumbersome if you have to add new geometries in the future. As [Clemens](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1136211/clemens) mentioned in the comments, sticking with rectangular images that are hit testable in the whole bounding rectangle will make the task immensely easier.

Comment: You might want to give the ShapeConverter a try to convert Adobe Illustrator, Adobe Photoshop, SVG, EPS to XAML Geometries, DrawingBrush or even C# code: [https://github.com/gomi42/ShapeConverter](https://github.com/gomi42/ShapeConverter)

Answer (score 2):

```
<Button>
    <Image Source="num1"/>
    <Button.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
        <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"/>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Button.Template>
</Button>
```

You can set the template of the button something like this:

```
<Image Source="num1.png" 
Width="16" 
Height="16"/>
```

Also this might help

```
<Button.Background>
   <ImageBrush ImageSource="num1.png" Stretch="Fill" TileMode="None" />
</Button.Background>
```

Comment: If I do this I'll have a rectangle area for a button. I want the number itself being a button.

Comment: Actual addition doesn't solve my problem as well. The area of button is still rectangular.

Answer (score -1):

You can draw a graph by yourself,and you can get Path Data via the link below
[Get path geometry from image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/983092/get-path-geometry-from-image)

```
<Button Width="100" Height="100" >
            <Button.Template >
                <ControlTemplate>

                        <Path x:Name="path" Data="xxxxx " Stretch="Fill" Fill="Azure" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
                            <Path.RenderTransform>
                                <TransformGroup>
                                    <ScaleTransform/>
                                    <SkewTransform/>
                                    <RotateTransform/>
                                    <TranslateTransform/>
                                </TransformGroup>
                            </Path.RenderTransform>
                            <Path.Effect>
                                <DropShadowEffect ShadowDepth="0" BlurRadius="22" Color="#FF646464"/>
                            </Path.Effect>

                        </Path>


                </ControlTemplate>
            </Button.Template>
        </Button>
```